# Jinja video and image files

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I am new to Google App engine and I am using jinja templates for rendering html.
My HTML page audio and video files and they are not getting rendered. Is there a way to get the images and video file working using jinja? Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving image and video static file handlers above the main.app fixed the issue